# How to allow for case insensitive URLs in DocPad?

Tags: docpad

I'd like to allow for case insensitive URLs within DocPad, e.g. *http://host.me/SomePath* should reference the same doc as *http://host.me/somepath* or */sOmEpAtH*.

I've already been looking at the cleanurls plugin, trying to find a matching hook in there ... but it seems it adds further `urls` only to the docs's meta information to allow for a extension less, and optionally a trailing slash, url.

How would I add in case insensitive URLs to DocPad?

Comment: What would you want this for? AFAIK this has never been a concern for URLs. I have not come across a website that fixes URLs if they're written wrong.

Comment: Very likely you have come along a lot of sites that are case insensitive and are fortunate enough not to realise so because they are.

If it is possible to prevent users from experiencing a 404 easily I would want it.

Comment: I have run across lots of 404s because of a caps, tons of times. The couple of ways I can come up with to achieve this is to either cover ALL cases and make a file for every possible variation, which is stupid because there'll be hundreds if not thousands of files for each URL. The other way is to configure some Apache URL rewrite rules or the equivalent for Nginx in order to detect these typos and fix them.

Comment: Sorry, but your comment does not make any point here.

Comment: For Apache there is http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_speling.html no need for custom rewrites btw.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your specific case, but it is possible to intercept urls in the docpad.coffee file. In particular I'm thinking of the "serverExtend" event where you can create a handler for "server.get". In that you can change all characters to lower case and then return the 'caseless' document using something like this:

```
document = docpad.getCollection('documents').findOne({relativeOutPath: 'nocapitals.html'});
            docpad.serveDocument({
                document: document,
                req: req,
                res: res,
                next: next,
                statusCode: 200
            });
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, sounds like that might be a good starting point.
How'd I change it so all docs are served caseless?

Comment: Steve, this requires the website to be hosted on a dynamic server no? In other words a Node.js server?

Comment: To allow for per-request handling you'll need to run docpad non-static ... yes.

Comment: Yep - you will need to be hosting your site on a docpad/node.js driven site. So not a static site.

Comment: @stackasec do you want to mark this answer as solved? It helps other people who might be searching for the same answer

Comment: I would if I'd think it answers my question. Unfortunately it does not.